# How can I scrape newloading from Onvista Optionsschein Bid and Ask to my Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet

Onvista Optionsschein to scrape http://www.onvista.de/optionsscheine/snapshot.html?ISIN=DE000HU5TD98

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dhfLt7S_kdeoKQymvxL4Y2gL92WLdKaL8nAsaAHyK0Y/pubhtml

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution, a solution, a solution: https://moz.com/blog/scraping-cleaning-your-data-with-google-sheets-closer-look